# Use Distnict with getContentREsolver android Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a messaging application in android and i want to get text messages from unique contact numbers only.

I tried following code but it is not working.

```
String[] projection = new String[] { "_id","DISTINCT "+ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, "person", "body", "date", "type" };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,null, null, null);
```

It throwing error here.

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "DISTINCT": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, DISTINCT number, person, body, date, type FROM sms ORDER BY date DESC
```

Can Some one please crack this out for me.

Comment: see [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

Comment: What is the minimum required Android version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query. The DISTINCT keyword only works with all rows. What you need is a Group By section in your query.

You could change your query to:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, "person", "body", "date", "type" };
String selection = GROUP BY " + ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, null);
```

I've not tested this yet, so there might be syntax errors.